# Bootstrap adding background images to a section

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

So I've been trying to add an image to a row in Bootstrap 4. The problem is it's only taking up a square of the section instead of the entire row. I believe I've done it before but I can't remember how I did it (of course). I figured this would be fairly simple to accomplish but I guess not.
Here is my code so far:

```css
/* Center align the text within the three columns below the carousel */
.marketing .col-lg-4 {
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
  text-align: center;
}
.marketing h2 {
  font-weight: 400;
}
.marketing .col-lg-4 p {
  margin-right: .75rem;
  margin-left: .75rem;
}

#bg-img {
  background-color: #E6F1FF;
  background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/600/800');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: 50% 20%;
  background-size: cover;
  color: #323840;
  height: 1148px;
 
  
 
  
 
}

.value-heading {
  color: #323840;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 34px;
  font-family: 'Inter-SemiBold', Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 41.15px;
}

.value-description {
  font-family: 'Inter-Regular', Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #323840;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 36px;
  
}

.section-heading {
  color: #043B7C;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 46px;
  font-family: 'Inter-Medium', Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main role="main">
      <div class="container marketing" >
      
        <div id="bg-img">
          <div class="pricing-header mx-auto text-center" >
            <h1 class="display-4">header</h1>

          </div>


        <div class="row">
          
          
          <div class="col-lg-4 ml-n5">
            <img class="rounded-circle" src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" alt="Generic placeholder image" width="200" height="200">
              <h2 class="mt-3 value-heading">header</h2>
              <p class="value-description">info</p>
    
          </div>

          <!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
          <div class="col-lg-4">
            <img class="rounded-circle" src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" alt="Generic placeholder image" width="200" height="200">
            <h2 class="mt-3 value-heading">header</h2>
              <p class="value-description">info</p>
    
          </div>
          <!-- /.col-lg-4 -->

          <div class="col-lg-4">
            <img class="rounded-circle" src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" alt="Generic placeholder image" width="200" height="200">
            <h2 class="mt-3 value-heading">header</h2>
              <p class="value-description">info</p>
    
          </div>
          <!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
          
        </div>
          
        <div class="row">
          
          
          <div class="col-lg-4 ml-n5">
            <img class="rounded-circle" src="#" alt="Generic placeholder image" width="200" height="200">
              <h2 class="mt-3 value-heading">header</h2>
              <p class="value-description">info</p>
    
          </div>

          <!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
          <div class="col-lg-4">
            <img class="rounded-circle" src="#" alt="Generic placeholder image" width="200" height="200">
            <h2 class="mt-3 value-heading">header</h2>
              <p class="value-description">info</p>
    
          </div>
          <!-- /.col-lg-4 -->

          <div class="col-lg-4">
            <img class="rounded-circle" src="#" alt="Generic placeholder image" width="200" height="200">
            <h2 class="mt-3 value-heading">header</h2>
              <p class="value-description">info</p>
    
          </div>
          <!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
          
        </div>  
          
          
          
        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->
        
        </div>
  </main>
```

[Link to Codepen](https://codepen.io/amyscotteng/pen/oNGaZzx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the background image to be on the `row` class then put it in there instead of putting it in your id element `bg-img`. Check the snippet below for reference.

```css
/* Center align the text within the three columns below the carousel */
.marketing .col-lg-4 {
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
  text-align: center;
}
.marketing h2 {
  font-weight: 400;
}
.marketing .col-lg-4 p {
  margin-right: .75rem;
  margin-left: .75rem;
}

.row {
  background-color: #E6F1FF;
  background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/600/800');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: 50% 20%;
  background-size: cover;
  color: #323840;
  height: 1148px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.value-heading {
  color: #323840;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 34px;
  font-family: 'Inter-SemiBold', Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 41.15px;
}

.value-description {
  font-family: 'Inter-Regular', Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #323840;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 36px;
  
}

.section-heading {
  color: #043B7C;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 46px;
  font-family: 'Inter-Medium', Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main role="main">
      <div class="marketing" >
        <div id="bg-img">
          <div class="pricing-header mx-auto text-center" >
            <h1 class="display-4">header</h1>
          </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-4 ml-n5">
            <img class="rounded-circle" src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" alt="Generic placeholder image" width="200" height="200">
              <h2 class="mt-3 value-heading">header</h2>
              <p class="value-description">info</p>
          </div>
          <!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
          <div class="col-lg-4">
            <img class="rounded-circle" src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" alt="Generic placeholder image" width="200" height="200">
            <h2 class="mt-3 value-heading">header</h2>
              <p class="value-description">info</p>
          </div>
          <!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
          <div class="col-lg-4">
            <img class="rounded-circle" src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" alt="Generic placeholder image" width="200" height="200">
            <h2 class="mt-3 value-heading">header</h2>
              <p class="value-description">info</p>
          </div>
          <!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-4 ml-n5">
            <img class="rounded-circle" src="#" alt="Generic placeholder image" width="200" height="200">
              <h2 class="mt-3 value-heading">header</h2>
              <p class="value-description">info</p>
          </div>
          <!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
          <div class="col-lg-4">
            <img class="rounded-circle" src="#" alt="Generic placeholder image" width="200" height="200">
            <h2 class="mt-3 value-heading">header</h2>
              <p class="value-description">info</p>
          </div>
          <!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
          <div class="col-lg-4">
            <img class="rounded-circle" src="#" alt="Generic placeholder image" width="200" height="200">
            <h2 class="mt-3 value-heading">header</h2>
              <p class="value-description">info</p>
          </div>
          <!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
        </div>  
        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->
        </div>
  </main>
```

Comment: Hi and thank you for your help! I updated my Codepen with your code and it doesn't work. The background image is still a square and it's not 100% of the width.

https://codepen.io/amyscotteng/pen/oNGaZzx

Comment: @metalcoder it's because of the bootstrap class that you are using on your `div` container. See this link: https://codepen.io/ypinbong/pen/OJxBmoK

Comment: Problem is if you remove the container, things are no longer centered on the page, nor are they responsive. :/

Comment: @metalcoder you can make `.marketing` responsive yourself. If you don't know how to, then I can only tell you to use *inspect element* on your page, and check which properties of `.container` bootstrap class caused the behavior that you don't want. After that, you can just override that with another class, adding `!important` to your own value would usually do the trick.

Comment: I've been avoiding using !important but I think that may be a viable solution. 
I really appreciate your help and you being nice! I've gone ahead and marked your answer as the correct one since it works and to help others. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get your question well but if you are asking about the background why it's not taking the whole section I believe that happens because you choose a portrait image you have to use a landscape one

```css
background-image: url(https://www.adorama.com/alc/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/landscape-photography-tips-yosemite-valley-feature.jpg);
```

Comment: It's landscape width, not portrait. Thank you, though!